# Listening for fragment changes in the browser address with Jxbrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

I would like to listen for address changes. So far I have been able to use:

```
browser.addStatusListener((StatusEvent event) -> {
    listener.handle(browser.getURL());
});
```

To create my own handler which is called when the address changes. But I just discovered that this approach does not work when an fragment is added to the address. E.g. a change from "http://example.com" to "http://example.com#hello" won't result in a StatusEvent. How do I archive this with JxBrowser?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are trying to listen for a status(that contains the URL of the link hovered by the mouse pointer) change?

Comment: I mean the current address of the browser (not the status bar). JxBrowser does not have an address bar but if it had it would be that value I am looking for changes in.

Answer (score 0):

The StatusListener class is not designed for tracking address changes.
In order to handle current browser URL changes, I suggest that you register your custom LoadListener and listen the DocumentLoadedInMainFrame event which indicates that a new document with a new URL was loaded in Browser instance. After you caught the DocumentLoadedInMainFrame event, you can get browser URL invoking the Browser.getURL() method. Please take a look at the code sample below:

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadAdapter;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.events.LoadEvent;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.swing.BrowserView;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class LoadHandlerSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView view = new BrowserView(browser);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        browser.addLoadListener(new LoadAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onDocumentLoadedInMainFrame(LoadEvent event) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("Document loaded: " + event.getBrowser().getURL());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```